# Regular expression to match environment

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using JavaScript and I'm looking for a regex to match the placeholder "environment", which will be a different value like "production" or "development" in "real" strings.

The regex should match "environment" in both strings:

```
https://company-application-environment.company.local
https://application-environment.company.local
```

I have tried:

- `[^-]+$` which matches `environment.company.local`
- `\.[^-]+$` which matches `.company.local`

How do I get environment?

Comment: How does that get production as a value in a "real" string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex based on a positive lookahead:

```
/[^.-]+(?=\.[^-]+$)/
```

**Details:**

- `[^.-]+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `-` and `.`
- `(?=\.[^-]+$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a dot and 1+ of non-hyphen characters till end.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhqEmk/2)

**Code:**

```js
const urls = [
  "https://company-application-environment.company.local", 
  "https://application-environment.company.local",
  "https://application-production.any.thing",
  "https://foo-bar-baz-development.any.thing"
]

const regex = /[^.-]+(?=\.[^-]+$)/;

urls.forEach(url =>
  console.log(url.match(regex)[0])
)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but since epascarello also included an example I choose that one as answer. I was a bit lost with "grab captured group #1". There is no way to avoid doing [1] to get the result?

Comment: ok I will post an answer that doesn't depend on capture group.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not the fanciest reg exp, but gets the job done.

```js
const urls = [
  "https://company-application-environment.company.local", 
  "https://application-environment.company.local", 
  "https://a-b-c-d-e-f.foo.bar"
]

urls.forEach(url =>
  console.log(url.match(/-([^-.]+)\./)[1])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Match for known environments

```js
var tests = [
  'https://company-application-development.company.local',
  'https://application-production.company.local',
  'https://appdev.company.local',
  'https://appprod.company.local'
];

tests.forEach(test => {
  var pattern = /(development|dev|production|prod)/g;
  var match = test.match(pattern);
  console.log(`environment = ${match}`);
});
```

In this case, the best way to match is to literally use the word you are looking for.

And if you need to match multiple values in the `environment` position, use the RegEx `or` format. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or).

```
(production|development)
```

Comment: Using mobile app and was in the middle of reviewing when you saw it. The basic answer remains the same.

Comment: What the value of environment will be, is not known. However, if I somehow manage to list all the combinations possible this might be helpful. With an added example to specially address the question this could have been a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I feel this format is more readable. I did forget to use () instead of []. Finally at desktop to add a snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), split on `-` and get the last item from the array. Then split on a dot and get the first item.

```js
[
  "https://company-application-environment.company.local",
  "https://application-environment.company.local"
].forEach(s => {
  let env = new URL(s).host.split('-').pop().split('.')[0];
  console.log(env);
})
```

Comment: I want to support other use cases as well, forcing me to use regex. Programming every use case is just no option. Clean solution though.